# InStr in Array not populating value if found

Tags: excel, vba

I've written the below code to search for a value(Supplier Name) in sheet "Fusion" Column H in sheet "CX" column D. I'm also doing a check the other way around so if the same value(Supplier Name) in sheet CX is in sheet "Fusion". I'm not looking for an Exact match hence the use of Instr and doing the comparison both ways as i'm not sure how a user has entered the information in either sheet.

The data type in either cell should be text.
If a match is found then in the last column of sheet "CX" it should just populate either "Supplier Found" or "Supplier Not Found"

Currently it's not populating the last column with any data but the Macro isn't erroring at any point.

I've tried adding msgboxes and "Here" and "Here3" are being triggered but it doesn't seem to be hitting the section of code that is "Here2" so I think it's there that's causing the issue but not sure how to resolve it.

Screenshot of my Data is :CX Sheet
[image]
Fusion Sheet
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit


Sub CompareCXFusion()

Dim CX As Worksheet
Dim Fusion As Worksheet

Dim strTemp as string
Dim strCheck as string

Dim i As Long, J As Long

Dim CXArr As Variant
Dim FusionArr As Variant

Dim match As Boolean

Dim CXRng As Range
Dim FusionRng As Range

Set CX = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CX")
Set Fusion = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fusion")

Set CXRng = CX.Range("A2", CX.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6))
Set FusionRng = Fusion.Range("A2", Fusion.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 9))

CXArr = CXRng.Value2
FusionArr = FusionRng.Value2

strTemp = lcase(trim(FusionArr(J, 7)))  
strCheck = lcase(trim(CXArr(i, 3))) 


For i = 1 To UBound(CXArr)
    Match = False
        For J = 1 To UBound(FusionArr)
        MsgBox "Here"
            If (Instr(strTemp, strCheck) > 0) OR (InStr(strCheck, strTemp) > 0) Then
                MsgBox"Here2"
                CXArr(i, 6) = "Supplier Found"
            Else
            Msgbox"Here3"
                CXArr(i, 6) = "Supplier not found"

        End If
    Next J
Next i
End Sub
```

The expected output i'd expect is: If in Column H of Fusion the Supplier Name is "Supplier A" and the value in Column D of sheet "CX" is "Supplier A LTD" then i'd expect it to populate column G in sheet CX with "Supplier Found" due to it being found in the string.

If you need any more info please let me know.

I don't know how to correctly insert examples of my data else I would have

Comment: You're populating an array - what are you trying to do with this array once it's filled? No where in this code are you writing anything to a column. Also, what is the purpose of `match`? `cell`?

Comment: Once I've populated the array I want to search for the 3rd element in the CXarr in the 7th element of the FusionArr and vice versa. I thought I was populating the 6th element in CXarr right at the end? CxArr(i,6) = "Supplier Found" ? Nothing. I've tried to amend some other code i've written and not realised I don't actually use those two Dim's at all so I'll delete those

Comment: you mean column of the array?

Comment: @MattWilliams *"Currently it's not populating the last column with any data but the Macro isn't erroring at any point."* - I'm wondering what you mean by this. Honestly I don't think there is any need for an array here - why not just work with the ranges?

Comment: @dwirony So I want to populate column G on Sheet "CX" either with "Supplier Found" or "Supplier Not Found" depending on whether the values are found in the array. I run the above code and it runs without error but nothing is being populated in column G sheet CX

Comment: @MattWilliams Like i said, nothing will populate column G in sheet CX because there is nothing in your code write now that writes to any worksheet - you're just writing to arrays which are stored at run-time and cleared at `End Sub`. You should rephrase your entire question and specify *what you're trying to do*.

Comment: @MattWilliams Can you post a screenshot of your sample data?

Comment: I would do the following: `If (Instr(LCase(trim(FusionArr(J, 7))), LCase(Trim(CXArr(i, 3)))) > 0) OR (InStr(lcase(Trim(CXArr(i, 3))), lcase(trim(FusionArr(J, 7))) > 0) Then`

Comment: @dwirony Hopefully the screenshots help. I need to improve on my posting and being more succinct in my questions so I do apologise and i'll amend it to make it more clear and appropriate. I honestly did think that I was correctly writing to column G  of CX sheet which should be (i,6) of the CXarr

Comment: @MattWilliams No worries, we just want to help and we can't if we can't tell what's going on :). Your first sentence is extremely ambiguous - *"I've written the below code to search for a value in sheet "Fusion" Column H in sheet "CX" column D. I'm also doing a check the other way around so if the same value in sheet CX is in sheet "Fusion"."* - What is "a value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Sub CompareCXFusion()
    Dim CX As Worksheet
    Dim Fusion As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, J As Long, lastRowCX As Long, lastRowFU As Long
    Dim CXText As String, FusionText As String
    Dim match As Boolean
    Dim CXRng As Range, FusionRng As Range

    Set CX = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CX")
    Set Fusion = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Fusion")

    lastRowCX = CX.Range("D1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row - 1
    lastRowFU = Fusion.Range("H1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row - 1

    Set CXRng = CX.Range("D1:D" & lastRowCX)
    Set FusionRng = Fusion.Range("H1:H" & lastRowFU)

    For i = 1 To lastRowCX
        match = False
            For J = 1 To lastRowFU
            'Debug.Print "Here"
                FusionText = FusionRng.Range("A1").Offset(J, 0).Value
                CXText = CXRng.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value
                If FusionText <> "" And CXText <> "" Then
                If InStr(FusionText, CXText) Or InStr(CXText, FusionText) Then
                    'Debug.Print "Here2"
                    match = True
                End If
                End If
            Next J


        'Result goes to column G of CX range:
        If match Then
            CXRng.Range("A1").Offset(i, 3).Value = "Supplier found" ' "Supplier found - " & i & " - " & CXRng.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Address & " - " & CXRng.Range("A1").Offset(i, 3).Address
        Else
            CXRng.Range("A1").Offset(i, 3).Value = "Supplier NOT found" '"Supplier NOT found - " & i & " - " & CXRng.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Address & " - " & CXRng.Range("A1").Offset(i, 3).Address
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked as intended. I'll be able to hopefully use this to then compare another 2 columns across sheets for an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to check for case sensitivity:

```
    Dim strTemp as string
    Dim strCheck as string 


    'Inside for I loop
        'Inside for j Loop
    strTemp = lcase(trim(FusionArr(J, 7)))  
    strCheck = lcase(trim(CXArr(i, 3)))  

    If (Instr(strTemp, strCheck) > 0) OR (InStr(strCheck, strTemp) > 0) Then 
        '...  

    End If
        'end for j
    'end for i
```

Comment: Why not us `vbTextCompare` instead?

Comment: @dwirony lcase is faster as the majority of letters are lowercase. where as text compare checks each char.  "Bear in mind that StrComp(,,vbTextCompare) [or for our case Instr()] is more than just a case-insensitive comparison. It's actually built for sorting, not comparing for equality. In many cases, such a locale-dependent textual comparison is an overkill and can even lead to subtle errors." - [link](http://www.aivosto.com/articles/stringopt.html)

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 I get a subscript out of range when I insert the above code to replace the line of the If statement. I've added the Dim and the strTemp+strCheck. What should I be removing and then where should I be inserting your code?

Comment: Can you update your code question to show your results and code?

Comment: @IAmNerd2000 I've edited my code to what I have now with your code inserted into where I thought it should have gone. The error message I get is "Subscript out of range"

Comment: The `strTemp=`  and `strCheck=` code should be within your J for loop.

Comment: also make sure to check the lower bound of your arrays. I see that the for loops start at 1, but the CXArr and FusionArr may not be 1.

Comment: I've amended the for loop to include LBound so thanks for that tip as I usually set it as 1. It's not erroring out now but it doesn't seem to trigger the second msgbox"Here2" so i'm pretty sure it must be not finding a match between the string in FusionArr in the CXArr as it's hitting the msgbox"Here3"

Comment: you need to remove the `If FusionText <> "" And CXText <> "" Then` if statement and End If. With the Instr Funtion, the result will be -1 if a blank string is added. Also, you didn't implement the code I suggested using `lcase()` and `trim()`.